# Updating drop down list loop

Tags: excel, vba, list, loops, dropdown

I'm trying to create a list which checks a database for the desired name and then adds that item to the drop down. The code I have so far works as in it checks the name but then overwrites any previous entries in the list. How can I alter so that it adds a new list item each time it finds the correct data?

```
While ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Inventory Database").Range("A" & j).Value <> ""
If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Inventory Database").Range("A" & j) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Equipment Availability").Cells(1, i) Then
dvList = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Inventory Database").Range("B" & j)

'~~> Creates the list 
With Sheets("Equipment Availability").Cells(2, 2).Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:=dvList
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
End If
j = j + 1
Wend
```

Comment: I can't quite tell what you are matching to. Is it when a particular cell changes or something is added to a list? Either way, you could probably use the sheet-change, or target change event.

Comment: This runs when the sheet is activated. The problem is I only get the last item of a series rather than the whole series as each time it runs the loop it destroys the last list and creates a new one with a single item. e.g. list should be "option 1" "option 2" "option 3" but it gives only "option 3"

Comment: Could you not do a separate delete statement outside of the loop, and remove that one? At the moment you're clearing the list before every add.

Comment: If I try and remove the .delete inside the loop I get an application-defined or object-defined error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only create the validation list once, while referencing a named range. If you expand the named range on every loop (adding the new value), then the validation list will automatically be updated.

Comment: So is it not possible to create a list that expands via a loop?

Comment: Yes it is, by expanding the range the list looks at. The list will grow with it

Comment: Ah so I need to create a separate named range in running the loop and then reference that range for the list.

Comment: You can create the list once, before or after the loop, or just manually in the excel sheet. All the loop does is expand the named range that the lists looks at